# number * price doesn't count properly

Tags: php, count

This is my first post so i hope it goes right.
(sorry for my bad english).

I will add some pictures here so you understand better then my typing.

What i dont understand is everywhere in my script where i put this:

[image: Query]

On my site i see this and that is ok:

[image: Site]

But in my email it shows different at the right, outcome is not 37,50 but 36,00 and not 45,00 but 44,00 :

[image: Mail]

Does anyone knows what to do? i tried all day but nothing works.
I hope you understand what i try to say ;-)

Sincerly,
Marc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't multiply the formatted number, because the number parser doesn't recognize `,` as a decimal point. When it parses the string `12,50`, it treats it as just `12`.

You should multiply the original value and then format it.

```
$subtotaal = $rowkosten['prijs'] * $rowaantal;
```

I can't explain why it's working on the web page. You must be using different code there.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thank you so much!!!! i tried a lot but not this and it's so easy if you know it lol i think it's better to change it everywhere so it's eveywhere how it supose to be. Tanks again, Marc